# How to resolve 'class constructor cannot be invoked without new' error when building with svelte, babel, and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, svelte

I'm trying to get svelte, webpack, and babel to work together. I am producing the minified bundle, however, this bundle is throwing errors upon loading it up in the browser. This needs to be compatible with IE11 while using ES6 syntax.

I get

> Class constructor I cannot be invoked without 'new'

The pertinent parts of my webpack looks as follows

```
      {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs|svelte)?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.js')
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.svelte$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "svelte-loader",
                options: {
                    emitCss: false, 
                    hotReload: false
                },
            },
        },
```

babel.config is as follows

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    'angularjs-annotate',
    'lodash'
],
presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true }
    }],
    '@babel/preset-react'
    ]
};
```

The svelte file itself is pretty basic

```
<script>
    export let name = "World";
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

**UPDATE**

I can get it to run by excluding transform-classes in babel config

```
exclude: ['transform-classes'],
```

However, this of course breaks IE11.

Comment: Which constructor are you calling? What is the stack trace of that exception?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update the webpack-cli and html-webpack-plugin versions in your package.json:

```
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",

"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.0",
```

Then, delete your node_modules and package-lock.json files and run a new npm install

Comment: Updating webpack-cli (from 4.2.0 to ^4.5.0) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

$ yarn remove webpack-cli && yarn add --dev webpack-cli

This will remove the old cli version, re-install the new one and compile everything afresh. Problem solved